# When element is set to fixed I lose a scroll bar

Tags: jquery, scroll, fixed

I have a page in which I have to prevent certain layers from scrolling up when they reach a certain position. I am using jQuery to accomplish that. I have done this across several pages with different layers with no issues.

However,, I came across this odd problem on one of the pages..

When I stop the element from scrolling I lose the window scroll bar.

I use this jQuery code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scrollTop > 404){
    $('#sub-header').css('position','fixed')
    $('#sub-header').css('top','66px')
  }
}); // close window scroll function
```

There are 12 more div elements following the one I am trying to lock and they are set to the height of 400px. I am confused as to why the window doesn't read the content below sub header. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Odd. Are you sure $('#sub-header') doesn't select more than you originally intended, for example because you forgot a closing tag?

Comment: it could be that everyone element has been set to fixed, that's why the scrollbar will be gone. There is nothing else to scroll to.

Comment: I just now realized that subsequent divs are not below the sub-header div but wrapped in it. I suppose setting the top to fixed would logically render the content in the fixed div un-scrollable.

Comment: Sumurai8, your comment made me re-inspect what wraps around what. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if the elements have been set to fixed, they wont get a scrollbar anymore, see here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BqaRW/

html

```
<div></div>
```

css

```
div{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 400px;

    position: fixed;
    bottom: -300px;
}
```

Comment: I resolved the issue. My subsequent divs are not below the sub-header div but wrapped in it. I suppose setting the top to fixed would logically render the content in the fixed div un-scrollable.

Comment: Oh,, it was not the div that lost the scroll bar,, it was the document window.. I do not need a scroll bar on the element.

Comment: I know, I might have said it wrong, but this is the cause that makes the scrollbar disappear

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case the issue was that the divs that were supposed to be under the fixed header actually were wrapped by the header. It is logical that a large div with a fixed height would automatically render it's overflowing content as un-scrolable. You can't fix and scroll the same element in a page at the same time.